# How can I catch exceptions in this monad stack?

Tags: haskell

I have the following monad stack:

```hs
import Control.Monad.Trans.State ( runStateT, StateT )
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except ( catchE, throwE, runExcept, Except )

type MyMonad a = StateT Int (StateT Char (Except String)) a

runMyMonad :: MyMonad a -> Char -> Int -> Either Error ((a, Int), Char)
runMyMonad f c i = runExcept $ runStateT (runStateT f i) c
```

If I want to throw an error in an action, I can do this:

```hs
-- Takes an Int and returns its double. 
-- Throws an error if it is not larger than 5.
myAction :: Int -> MyMonad Int
myAction a = 
    if a > 5 
        then return $ a*2 
        else lift . lift $ throwE "There was an error"
```

That works, but I can't catch that error in another action like this:

```hs
-- Returns 0.
myBaseAction :: MyMonad Int
myBaseAction = return 0

-- Takes an Int and returns its double. 
-- Returns 0 if it is not larger than 5.
mySafeAction :: Int -> MyMonad Int
mySafeAction a = lift . lift $ catchE (myAction a) (\e -> myBaseAction)
```

Haskell complains about the types of the arguments of `catchE`, saying that it expected an `ExceptT` but I gave it a `MyMonad`. How can I make `catchE` take `MyMonad`? I've read about the `liftCatch` function in some posts, but I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to use `throwError` and `catchError` from the [`mtl`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Error-Class.html) library. Appropriate instances of the associated class have already been written for all the transformers defined in the `transformers` library. So, that would look like this:

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Except

myAction :: Int -> MyMonad Int
myAction a = 
    if a > 5 
        then return $ a*2 
        else throwError "There was an error"

mySafeAction :: Int -> MyMonad Int
mySafeAction a = catchError (myAction a) (\e -> return 0)
```

In fact, it's even quite normal to characterize your monad stack by the effects used in a particular action:

```
myAction' :: MonadError String m => Int -> m Int
myAction' = {- same as before -}

mySafeAction' :: MonadError String m => Int -> m Int
mySafeAction' = {- same as before -}
```

This can be specialized to `m ~ MyMonad` at the top level of your application.

...but you will have a sad surprise when you go to use `MonadState` in this way with your transformer! See [`effect-stack`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/effect-stack) for one approach at dealing with that problem.

Comment: So, just to make sure I understand: I use the transformers to create my stack just as I did, and instead of lifting `catchE` and `throwE` manually, I use `catchError` and `throwError` which are functions in the interface of `MonadError`. Since `StateT` and `ErrorT` have instances for `MonadError`, it works out of the box. Is that right?

Comment: @AlejandroDeCicco Got it in one! (Only quibble: you should continue using `Except`/`ExceptT` over `ErrorT`. `Except`(`T`) also has the appropriate instances.)

Answer (score 0):

I will answer this since I ended up finding a solution, and I couldn't find any other answers.

The function I had to use for lifting was `liftCatch` from `Control.Monad.Trans.State`. The code now looks like this:

```hs
import Control.Monad.Trans.State ( liftCatch )

-- Takes an Int and returns its double. 
-- Returns 0 if it is not larger than 5.
mySafeAction :: Int -> MyMonad Int
mySafeAction a = (liftCatch $ liftCatch catchE) (myAction a) (\e -> myBaseAction)
```

Edit: this is the way to lift it manually, but Daniel's solution above is a lot cleaner